# MySql + Qt 5.8: "Incorrect string value" Statement Containing Degree Symbol

Tags: mysql, qt

This is my problem: We have upgraded from Qt 5.7 to Qt 5.8, and suddenly all our SQL statements containing special characters fails.

I have made a simple test program attempting to execute the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO db_object_staticinfo(object_id, object_id_suffix, description, short_description, object_type, is_persistent, customer_tag, fluid_type) VALUES('BLAAA1', "BLAAA1", "Energy at 25°C total", "Energy at 25°C total", 1000, 1, 'BLAAA1', 2)
```

The database error text returned is:

*Incorrect string value: '\xB0C tot...' for column 'description' at row 1*

The degree symbol has indeed the UTF code 0xB0, **but why is it suddenly invalid?**

Some details: We are using MySQL 5.7 on Windows 10.
The database table character set has not changed compared to our Qt 5.7 solution (which is working fine).
The degree sign is well within a 1-byte UTF-8, isn't it? Inspecting the part of the string containing the mischief character shows the following content:

```
[210]   0x0032 '2'  unsigned short
[211]   0x0035 '5'  unsigned short
[212]   0x00b0 '°'  unsigned short
[213]   0x0043 'C'  unsigned short
```

**Any ideas of what is going on here??**

Answer (score 0):

`object_id = > BLAAA1` ???? see coresponding

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (value1, value2, value3)
```